# How much tax should I expect to pay on $1850 per month of PhD stipend in Virginia as an international student on study visa?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, f1-student-visa

First $5000 are tax free due to a treaty.
The money is from a teaching assistantship.

According to the internet state tax is < 5%.

Are there any other taxes like federal tax etc?
Are taxes paid at the end of year or from the first payment?

Comment: Do you have other income? Taxes would be calculated based on your total US income.

Comment: @keshlam No. Just the PhD stipend. 20hr/week TA duty.

Comment: That should be far below the threshold where income tax starts. Technically you should fill out the form anyway.

Comment: Usually if you're being paid for TA work that is considered wages/salary (rather than a stipend) and taxes will be withheld from your paycheck.  You should check with your department or the school's financial aid/billing office how this will be handled.